# SVN : What's the difference between --non-interactive and --accept postpone ?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to understand the difference between those two option of the `svn update` command. 
I have, admittedly quickly, looked at the book but didn't find anything useful.

I also tried both with conflicts, and both display the same text, and so on (`svn version 1.6.12`). Nothing about that on the web.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have a question about Apache Subversion refer to [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/).

- [`--non-interactive`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive) is a global option and means *"do no interactive prompting"*,
- [`--accept postpone`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.accept) is a valid option of [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) command and means *"take no resolution action at all and instead allow the conflicts to be recorded for future resolution".*

Global options apply to all svn.exe subcommands, even if they have no effect on some of them, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw:

> The svn command-line client usually exits quickly with an error if you
>   pass it an option which does not apply to the specified subcommand.
>   **But as of Subversion 1.5, several of the options which apply to all—or
>   nearly all—of the subcommands have been deemed acceptable by all
>   subcommands, even if they have no effect on some of them. (This change
>   was made primarily to improve the client's ability to called from
>   custom wrapping scripts.)** These options appear grouped together in the
>   command-line client's usage messages as global options, as can be seen
>   in the following bit of output.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it seems that an `svn update --non-interactive` did the exact things that a `svn update --accept postpone`, at least for conflicts.

It is like the `--accept postpone` option is included in the `--non-interactive`

Comment: (And I want to be sure that the `--accept postpone` option is included in the `--non-interactive` one).

Comment: It's seems pretty logical to me that in some cases `svn update --non-interactive` works the same way as `svn update --accept postpone`. It works non-interactively and allows you to solve conflicts later.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Thanks !

Comment: BTW, I think that you may want to ask this question in Apache Subversion USERS mailing list to get 100% correct and precise answer: http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Comment: Done : `When in non-interactive mode, Subversion can't ask you how you want to handle conflicts.  So, by default, yes, --accept=postpone is the mode that the update will operate in.  You can, however, choose a different mode with --accept=SOMETHING_ELSE if you wish.` Perfect !